# iOS table view navigation controller with multiple views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have an iOS 7 application that has a Tab Bar controller. On one tab I have a tableView, from which I can select a cell, and navigate to a detail view.

On the detail view I had the following to be able to navigate to another view:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Table View Cell Clicked on row: %ld", indexPath.row + 1);

    ThirdViewController *view = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:[NSBundle  mainBundle]];
    modelView.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
}
```

But this does not let me navigate to the new View. How can I navigate to multiple view, I require this:

View1 -> View2 -> View3 -> View4 -> View5 -> View6 - All these view contain a table view, and the selection to another view is by selecting on row on the table.

Thanks
Best Regards

UPDATED:
Problem solved. the last table view did to add the delegate outlet set. That wa the problem. Thanks

Comment: Your question says you have a "Tab Bar" controller, but in your code you're using a navigation controller.  Which is it?  Both?  Is `self.navigationController == nil` when you run this code?

Comment: I have a tab bar controller and within one tab item I have a navigation controller. So to your question it is both I think.

Comment: Upssss, problem solved. the last table view did to add the delegate outlet set. That wa the problem. Thanks

Comment: You should typically set a breakpoint and step through your code before you post here :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if `self.navigationController` is nil. If it is, it means you need to add navigation controller to the tab view controller:

```
[tabViewControllers addObject:[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myTableViewController]]; 
tabBarController.viewControllers = tabViewControllers;
```